# uc-logic tablet

Tags: tablet

I want to use my uc logic wp8060 tablet on linux. I downloaded and installed wizard-pen driver. When I do a lsusb, it does show with the right model. when I move the pen, nothing happens. And I have new battery in it

Comment: This question is also related 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/547041/pen-tablet-mousepen-doesnt-work-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the driver from http://digimend.github.io/ (old wiki at http://digimend.sourceforge.net/wiki/DIGImend ). They recommend *against* using the wizardpen driver generally. I'm using a modified version of their driver for my Huion h610 successfully, for whatever it's worth.